# jquery trigger conflict for light-box pop-up

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, triggers

This may be a silly question (aren't they all?), but I've been stumped on something for a while now...
I'm trying to build a lightbox-type pop-up for displaying details about a list item in a definition list.  I've got the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` working correctly, but I'm getting bugs if I try to trigger the same even on a different list item while the pop-up is still active.

Here's the code I'm working with...

```
    <html>, etc...
    <div>
       <dl>
        <dt>Trigger Element</dt>
        <dd>
            <div>
            (lightbox content)
            </div>
        </dd>
       <dl>
        <dt>Trigger Element</dt>
        <dd>
            <div>
            (lightbox content)
            </div>
        </dd>
       Etc....
     </dl>

 (function() {
    // Highlight the target dt items
    $('div.cigar-pop').parent().prev().addClass('cigar-highlight');

    // Initialize the lightbox functionality
    $('dd').children('div').addClass('hidden');
    $('dt').on('click', function() {
        //I'm still not entirely sure why this part worked...
        var $this = this;
        $(this).next()
            .children('div')
                .addClass('active')
                    .fadeIn(800, function($this) {
                        $('body').one('click', function(){ 
                            $('.active').fadeOut('fast')
                                .removeClass('active');
            });
        });
    });

    })();
```

I'm betting it's something simple, but I can't figure out what.  Sorry if this is a little rudimentary for this forum's unparalleled genius :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check to see if there's an `.active` element already, and just return.

```
$('dt').on('click', function() {
    if($('.active').length) return; // do not return false;
    // Your code
```

This will prevent the rest of your code in this function block from executing. In other words, when there is an `.active` element, the behaviour of clicking on another `dt` would be to hide the current `.active` element, rather than show a new one.

The reason we don't `return false;` is that this would stop the event from propagating, which is what we need it to do to reach the `body`, so the current `.active` element gets removed/hidden.